# How should I translate this sentence in Le Comte de Monte Cristo?

Tags: que

C'était, comme on le voit, un homme plein d'humanité que cet inspecteur, et bien digne des fonctions philanthropiques qu'il remplissait.

I am not familiar with the usage of “que cet” in this context. Thanks!

Comment: Where are your attempts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a common turn of phrase so it's no surprise it puzzles you.

*Que* is here a *conjonction* introducing a *proposition subordonnée relative*. Its *antécédent* is *un homme plein d'humanité*. This optional clause is there to clarify which man is being referred to.

*Que* is literary and usually replaced by a comma in everyday's French :

> *C'était, comme on le voit, un homme plein d'humanité, cet inspecteur, [...]*

The sentence can be rephrased this way:

> *Comme on le voit, cet inspecteur était un homme plein d'humanité, et bien digne des fonctions philanthropiques qu'il remplissait.*

A similar ***que*** can be found in this quote:

> ***Quel grand homme que ce Guillaume prince d’Orange !** Il trouva des esclaves, et il en fit des hommes libres.*
> Voltaire, *Dictionnaire philosophique*, 1764

It can be translated as:

> What a great man this William Prince of Orange was!

Comment: "It can be translated to", **clunky**, in fact not the right word.

Comment: @Lambie Merci mais la prochaine fois, propose une version corrigée, ce sera plus constructif.

Comment: Personally, I don't mind someone saying, I would say this instead of that. Or x is not really grammatical, it should be x.

Comment: @Lambie À la bonne heure !